# Can we use same data connection in Azure Data Explorer for ingesting data into different tables?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

I am completely new to Azure Data Explorer. I am working on a requirement now and I would like to know the possible approach for below scenario.

- I am generating multiple csv files in storage account container (say
  employee.csv, salary.csv , department.csv etc.).
- I am having related tables in the Azure Data Explorer (say Employee,
  Salary, Department etc).
- I am trying to create a Event Grid (Blob Storage) data connection to
  ingest the data into ADX tables on blob file creation.

Now, my query is I would like to know if we can use same data connection for all the tables or do I need to create a separate data connection for each table/csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have dynamic routing to different databases/tables.
see:

- [Event Grid data connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-event-grid-overview)

  - [Events routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-event-grid-overview#events-routing)

    - [Route event data to an alternate database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-event-grid-overview#route-event-data-to-an-alternate-database)
    - [Route event data to an alternate table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-event-grid-overview#route-event-data-to-an-alternate-table)